# Como condicionar serializer? DjangoRestFramework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, djangorestframework

Tengo el siguiente serializer:

```
class PerfilSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usuario = UserSerializer()
    seguidores = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    looks = LookSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    colecciones = ColeccionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        fields = ['id','usuario','boutique','tel','tel_fijo','entrg_pais','entrg_dep',
            'entrg_ciudad','entrg_direccion','entrg_cp','rmt_pais','rmt_dep',
            'rmt_direccion','rmt_ciudad','rmt_cp','num_cc','avatar','descp_armario',
            'tipo_ident','cedula_o_nit','propietario_cc','banco','tipo_cc','follow','seguidores',
            'notificacion_follow','colecciones']
```

Las variables looks y colecciones son relaciones con otros dos serializer.

El tema es que quiero mostrar una de las dos según si la variable `boutique` sea `True` o `False`. En caso de ser `True` mostrar `colecciones` y en caso de ser `False`, mostrar `looks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lo que necesitas, puedes ayudarte del método `to_representation` que te ofrece la API de la siguiente forma:

```
class PerfilSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usuario = UserSerializer()
    seguidores = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    looks = LookSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    colecciones = ColeccionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        fields = ['id','usuario','boutique','tel','tel_fijo','entrg_pais','entrg_dep',
        'entrg_ciudad','entrg_direccion','entrg_cp','rmt_pais','rmt_dep',
        'rmt_direccion','rmt_ciudad','rmt_cp','num_cc','avatar','descp_armario',
        'tipo_ident','cedula_o_nit','propietario_cc','banco','tipo_cc','follow','seguidores',
        'notificacion_follow', 'colecciones', 'looks']

    def to_representation(self, obj):  # obj es la instancia del objeto
       data = super(PerfilSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
       if obj.boutique:
           data.pop('looks', None)
       else:
           data.pop('colecciones', None)
       return data
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. muchas gracias.